# Filter/archive SMS messages from specific senders and send them to PC without going to computer

Tags: iphone, sms

A friend stumped me with an odd request. 
His platform is iPhone 4S with iOS 7. His computer is a PC with Windows 7.

The question is: how can he have SMS messages from a specified set of phone numbers to be sent to his computer and *not* appear on his phone?

He does not want to block calls from these numbers, and he wants to be able to read the text messages on his PC, but not on his phone.

My first thought was Google Voice, but I only see how to filter calls and not text messages.

I have found some iOS apps that will blacklist/block text messages from some numbers, but not any that will block them on the phone and send them to a PC (or a Mac, but he doesn't use a Mac).

Comment: Honestly, I think the first, and biggest hump you have to get over is the fact that computers don't receive SMS (in general). That part needs to be figured out, and as far as I know, that limits you right away to G Voice or a similar service. Even if he had a Mac, Macs only receive natively iMessages - not SMS. If it was iMessages that he would like to filter on a all-Apple setup, I expect you could work something out, but SMS is obviously different.

Comment: Google Voice is an option for him. The question was actually posed as "can I use Google Voice on my iPhone to...". Since it sounds like it's not an Apple-specific question, where would be the right place to ask this?

Comment: What I mean is that it's not really a web apps question, since it involves the iPhone also, so webapps stackexchange doesn't seem right either.

Comment: Good for you for pursuing this for your friend. I think the solution (if there is one), could be a little obscure. I would try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). There is a Google Voice app on iOS, but I'm not sure how long it will be around - it hasn't been updated to iOS 7 yet (but is still usable).